# How to add a bookmark to an arbitrary URL in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, web

This is more 'merely competent user' than 'super user' but how does one create a bookmark to a URL in Safari?

If I have a URL to a download (i.e. a resource with a MIME type that causes a download rather than displaying the content in the browser) I cannot see a way to add a bookmark for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

#### Copy Address from Download

Open the *Downloads* popup window in Safari, right-click the download file, and select *Copy Address*. Select *Bookmarks » Show All Bookmarks*, and press `Cmd-V` to paste the URL and create a bookmark for it.

#### Edit an existing bookmark

Just replace the URL of an existing bookmark.

#### Drag & drop a link to it, or its URL as text

If you have a link to the file, or just its URL as text, you can drag & drop it onto the *Bookmarks Bar* and create a bookmark there, or onto a window showing all bookmarks, adding it to the selected folder.

This should work for links in most applications, e.g. from Mail as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add bookmark to any (dummy) page, then go to bookmark collection and edit the address (URL) of the dummy page and replace it with download URL.

I have no experience with Safari, but in Chrome there's a `Bookmark bar`, and to add any URL (if its displayed as a hyperlink on the page) can be **dragged and dropped** to that bar to add as bookmark.

Comment: Yes, this rings a bell, I think I have actually done this before (the editing an existing bookmark 'hack').